# Regex to validate characters before period are A-Z and after only one space

Tags: regex

I need a regex that characters before period (if it is there) are 'A' through 'Z' or 'a' through 'z',  and after the only valid character is a space (possibly followed by more characters). Therefore the following should match:

```
Mr. Smith
SMITH MR. (space here)
dr. Jones MD. (space here)
Guy Here
HERE GUY
```

I am currently trying to use the following regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]*\.\s)[a-zA-Z]*
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: what's wrong with the regex you tried?

Comment: That is not clear at all. You say there must be a space after the letters, but then `dr. Jones` can't match.

Comment: My apologies. When I say after I mean after the period. Not after the letters. Therefore:
"dr. Jones" should work
but "dr. Jones MD." should fail. 
Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match either *not* a dot, or a dot surrounded by the appropriate stuff:

```
^([^.]|(?<=[a-zA-Z])\.(?= ))*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/BiHO73JWkX).

Breaking it down:

- `^` start
- `[^.]` non-dot
- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` previous char was a letter
- `\.` a dot
- `(?= )` next char is a space
- `$` end

And there's an alternation there `(a|b)*` means "any number of `a` or `b`".

Comment: Thank you! And an excellent explanation! It's great when someone breaks it down and I can learn from what they are saying.

Comment: `(?<=[a-zA-Z]) previous char was a dot` ??

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Doh! It was very early in the morning here... :/